# how i can break permission inheritance + remove some user groups from a newly created sub-site inside my event receiver

Tags: 2013, development, event-receivers, solution-package, farm-solution

I am working on building a new event receiver which get fired when item is updated, inside my sharepoint enterprise server 2013.

now inside the event receiver i am doing the following main steps:-

1. create a new sub-site.
2. set its master page.
3. stop inheriting permission
4. then remove a group named "rootUserOnly" . as those users should not be able to access the newly created sub-site.

so my event receiver ended up with the following code:-

```
   public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
               base.ItemUpdated(properties);
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
    {
       using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.SiteId))

       {

            string currenweburl = properties.RelativeWebUrl;//string currentweburl3 = properties.Web.WebTemplate;
            using (SPWeb spCurrentSite = site.OpenWeb(currenweburl))
            {

                    //code goes here....
                    //1 Create the subsite based on the template from the Solution Gallery
                    SPWeb newSite = spCurrentSite.Webs.Add(curItemID, curItemSiteName, "created automatically after adding a new project item", Convert.ToUInt16(1033), webTemplate, false, false);


                    //2 inherate navigation from parent
                    newSite.Navigation.UseShared = true;

                    //3 set its master page to a custom.master
                    string masterPage = "Custom.master";
                    var masterUri = new Uri(rootWeb.Url + "/_catalogs/masterpage/" + masterPage);
                    newSite.MasterUrl = masterUri.AbsolutePath;
                    newSite.CustomMasterUrl = masterUri.AbsolutePath;

                    //4 break the permission inheritance
                    newSite.BreakRoleInheritance(true,true);

                    //5 remove from this subsite a group named "rootUsersOnly"
                    SPGroup group = newSite.SiteGroups["rootUsersOnly"];
                    newSite.RoleAssignments.RemoveById(group.ID);



                    //update then dispose
                    newSite.Update();
                    newSite.Close();





                }
            }
        }
   });
//
        }


    }
}
```

but i am not sure if i am doing this in the correct way ? now i did a test and the sub-site was created successful + it got the correct master page + its have unique permission + the security group named "rootUsersOnly" does not exists inside the sub-site.
so can anyone advice on this please ?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the line as below:

```
//code goes here....
//1 Create the subsite based on the template from the Solution Gallery
SPWeb newSite = spCurrentSite.Webs.Add(curItemID, curItemSiteName, "created automatically after adding a new project item", Convert.ToUInt16(1033), webTemplate, true, false);
```

By setting it to true, you will inherit unique permission.

Explanation -

useUniquePermissions - set it to true to create a subsite that does not inherit permissions from another site.

When you do that, you can remove the below line:

```
//4 break the permission inheritance
newSite.BreakRoleInheritance(true,true);
```

Other than that, code looks good.

Reference - [SPWebCollection.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms412285.aspx)

Comment: so you mean my current appraoch should be fine also but i am adding extra nu-necessary step of breaking the role inheritance ,, which i can do when creating the new sub-site and pass "true,false" instead of "true,true" ? is this correct?

Comment: yes thats correct. Modify step 1 as given and remove step 4.

Comment: your approach will not work the same !! now if i modify my code as you mentioned i will end up without any security groups on the new subsite,, and only the "system account" is granted to access the new subsite.. while using my appraoch the new sub-site will have the all the security groups from his parent ,, except the rootUsersOnly... so can you adivce if your appraoch works differently at your end ?

Comment: can you adivce on my above comment please?

Comment: Leave it as it is then. Tested the code at my end as well , `spCurrentSite.Webs.Add(curItemID, curItemSiteName, "created automatically after adding a new project item", Convert.ToUInt16(1033), webTemplate, true, false);` , when this is used it removes the sharepoint groups as well. So your current code is alright.